# Python Pandas join aggregated tables

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with two columns: product_id and rating. I'm trying to join two tables. One obtained from

```
a = data.groupby('product_id').count()
```

The other one

```
b = data.groupby('product_id').mean()
```

I'd like to have a table that has on its columns the

```
product_id  count   mean
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
data.groupby('product_id').agg(['mean', 'count'])
```